# Making a checkbox to have check after a condition

Tags: c#

How do i make a certain checkbox will have a check after I clicked a button?
Is my code right or how do i modify it?

```
  if(condition)
  {
      checkbox.Checked = true;
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried your code, or its better to write question at SO then run Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or for both auto checking AND unchecking:

```
checkbox.Checked = condition;
```